# Value always return 0 while calculating

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I was doing an assignment for my subject here and in the assignment, every student is required to create a simple C++ program. The problem here is, when I do not assign a default to a variable, a compile error will occur. However, when I assign a default value (in this case, value = 0), the value will always be 0.

My question is, is there any way to solve this problem while not encountering the compile error?

If there was a similar question asked, could you please also, include the link to the solved question as well? Thank you very much!

[**Edit #1**: To those who wonder why the code is "messy", I only used simple commands and did not use object oriented components, if/else statements etc. The project created was meant to be composed of "simple codes".]

[**Edit #2**: This is the output display that I snapped:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNzkD.png

The Total Discounted fee part should be displaying numbers instead of default value 0]

(Microsoft Visual Studio Pro 2013; C++)

Expected output display:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTAqK.png

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /* Declare variables */
    int qtyVehicleCar, qtyVehicleTaxi, qtyVehicleTruck; // User input

    double feeOriginalCar, feeTotalOriginalCar, rateDiscountCar, feeTotalDiscountedCar, feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar; // variables for vehicle Car
    double feeOriginalTaxi, feeTotalOriginalTaxi, rateDiscountTaxi, feeTotalDiscountedTaxi, feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi; // variables for vehicle Taxi
    double feeOriginalTruck, feeTotalOriginalTruck, rateDiscountTruck, feeTotalDiscountedTruck, feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck; // variables for vehicle Truck
    double feeRepTotalOriginalFee, feeRepTotalDiscountedFee, feeRepTotalAfterDiscounted; // Generate final output

    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << "====== Malaysia Highway Company =====\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << "=====================================\n";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter quantity of the vehicles on 1st January 2014: " << endl;
    cout << "Car\t\t:\t";
    cin >> qtyVehicleCar;

    cout << "Taxi\t\t:\t";
    cin >> qtyVehicleTaxi;

    cout << "Truck\t\t:\t";
    cin >> qtyVehicleTruck;

    /* Lay out the Report table */
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "Report\n";
    cout << "--------\n";
    cout << endl;

    /* ============================== */
    /* Declaration prior to process */
    /* ============================== */

    /* The problematic part
    feeTotalDiscountedCar = 0;
    feeTotalDiscountedTaxi = 0;
    feeTotalDiscountedTaxi = 0;
    */

    // Prices
    feeOriginalCar = 2.00;
    feeOriginalTaxi = 1.00;
    feeOriginalTruck = 3.50;

    feeTotalOriginalCar = feeOriginalCar * qtyVehicleCar;
    feeTotalOriginalTaxi = feeOriginalTaxi * qtyVehicleTaxi;
    feeTotalOriginalTruck = feeOriginalTruck * qtyVehicleTruck;

    // In percentage
    rateDiscountCar = 2;
    rateDiscountTaxi = 10;
    rateDiscountTruck = 15;

    feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar = (rateDiscountCar/100) * feeTotalOriginalCar;
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi = (rateDiscountTaxi/100) * feeTotalOriginalTaxi;
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck = (rateDiscountTruck/100) * feeTotalOriginalTruck;

    // Final total - to be displayed
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar = feeTotalOriginalCar - feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar;
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi = feeTotalOriginalTaxi - feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi;
    feeTotalOriginalTruck = feeTotalOriginalTruck - feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck;

    feeRepTotalOriginalFee = feeTotalOriginalCar + feeTotalOriginalTaxi + feeTotalOriginalTruck;
    feeRepTotalDiscountedFee = feeTotalDiscountedCar + feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi + feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck;
    feeRepTotalAfterDiscounted = feeRepTotalOriginalFee - feeRepTotalDiscountedFee;

    /* ================= */
    /* Declaration END */
    /* ================= */

    /* Gives the following variables a default value, they will be modified later by the program */
    feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck = 0;
    feeTotalDiscountedTruck = 0;

    /* Processes */
    cout << "Item\t\t\t\t" << "Car\t" << "Taxi\t" << "Truck\t" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Original fee\t\t\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalTruck << endl;
    cout << "Quantity\t\t\t" << qtyVehicleCar << "\t" << qtyVehicleTaxi << "\t" << qtyVehicleTruck << endl;
    cout << "Total original fee\t\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeOriginalTruck << endl;
    cout << "Discount rate\t\t\t" << rateDiscountCar << "%\t" << rateDiscountTaxi << "%\t" << rateDiscountTruck << "%\t" << endl;
    cout << "Total discounted fee\t\t" << "RM " << feeTotalDiscountedCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalDiscountedTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalDiscountedTruck << endl;
    cout << "Total after discounted fee\t" << "RM " << feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi << "\t" << "RM " << feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck << endl;
    cout << endl;

    /* Displays output */
    cout << "Total original fee\t\t:\t" << "RM " << feeRepTotalOriginalFee << endl;
    cout << "Total discounted fee\t\t:\t" << "RM " << feeRepTotalDiscountedFee << endl;
    cout << "Total after discounted fee\t:\t" << "RM " << feeRepTotalAfterDiscounted << endl;
    cout << endl << endl;

    /* Displays end line */
    cout << "------------------- End of Program -------------------" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which variable? what error?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about `feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck` and `feeTotalDiscountedTruck`, your comment says "they will be modified later" -- but I see no code that would ever modify them.

Comment: (1) Enable compiler warnings, (2) re-compile, (3) read warnings, (4) understand warnings, (5) fix warnings, (6) profit !

Comment: Hi! It's "Total Discounted Fee" (feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar/Truck/Taxi). Here's the output display that I screenshoted:

Comment: You're using uninitialised variables in your calculations ! Read the compiler warnings !

Comment: @PaulR can you explain in detail about that? I did read the compiler warnings, and according to answers I found, they suggested me to give the variables a default value (in this case, 0). But the program did not function as programmed as the value does not change at all.

Comment: @PaulRoub that's exactly why I'm stuck at the moment. Do you have any suggestions to alter this part? This could be crucial for my next programming exercise/assignments.

Comment: The values won't magically change on their own. You're not doing *anything at all* to set new values for them. Are they supposed to be calculated based on the other variables? Input by the user?

Comment: It should be mentioned that "_The project created was meant to be composed of "simple codes"_" is not the same as "_write everything in a single function doing computation and formatting_". Small, modular programs are simple. Avoiding functions and data structures is not simple.

Comment: @PaulRoub yes, the value to be assigned is based on other variables.

Comment: @Rook Thank you very much. As you mentioned, this is a small and quite plain straightforward program. I still haven't touch the complex part of C++, so my lecturer advises me to stick to this "messy part".

Answer (score 2):

An uninitialized variables warning can mean either (1) you forgot to initialize something or (2) you thought you initialized it but didn't. Looks to me that in this case it's the second problem. Your variable names are mixed up.

For example,

```
feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar = (rateDiscountCar/100) * feeTotalOriginalCar;
feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi = (rateDiscountTaxi/100) * feeTotalOriginalTaxi;
feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck = (rateDiscountTruck/100) * feeTotalOriginalTruck;
```

These are supposed to be the amounts of the discounts, no? So why are you storing them into `feeTotalAfterDiscountedSomething` rather than `feeTotalDiscountedSomething`?

Similarly,

```
feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar = feeTotalOriginalCar - feeTotalAfterDiscountedCar;
feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi = feeTotalOriginalTaxi - feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi;
feeTotalOriginalTruck = feeTotalOriginalTruck - feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck;
```

Why is the third one storing the result into `feeTotalOriginalTruck` instead of `feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck`? (Note also that if you fix the first problem above, the rhs of the subtraction will also need to change).

Also,

```
feeRepTotalDiscountedFee = feeTotalDiscountedCar + feeTotalAfterDiscountedTaxi + feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck;
```

Similar problem. These should, I believe, all be `feeTotalDiscountedSomething` rather than `feeTotalAfterDiscountedSomething`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler rightfully complains that `feeTotalDiscountedCar` and `feeTotalDiscountedTaxi` are uninitialized. You need to initialize them somewhere. Maybe you want the user to enter them somewhere like this:

```
  cout << "Discount Fee Total Taxi:";
  cin >> feeTotalDiscountedTaxi;

  cout << "Discount Fee Total Car:";
  cin >> feeTotalDiscountedCar;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The discount fee for the three vehicles is to be calculated by the program, and then putting the value into the variables (something like carry forward). 

Since it is impossible to put a value into these variables, is there anyway to take the value calculated from another variable and fit them into those variables?

Or is there any other turnaround?

Answer (score 0):

why are you setting them to zero just before printing out?

`feeTotalAfterDiscountedTruck = 0;
feeTotalDiscountedTruck = 0;`

It will show the error because you are trying to use the variable with out initializing it.

Comment: OK.. so how do I tackle about that? The compiler will show me a warning if the variable has no values in it. In this case, the value for the variable will be taken from another variable.